# Error with Oh My ZSH themes, ZSH_THEME="random

Tags: zsh

I get the following message after installing Oh My ZSH and changing `ZSH_THEME="robbyrussel"` to `ZSH_THEME="random"` in .zshrc.

> Users/me/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:110: no such file or
>   directory: /Users/me/.oh-my-zsh/themes/“random”.zsh-theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `"`'s from the `ZSH_THEME` variable. You want:

```
ZSH_THEME=random
```

in your `.zshrc` file. [See the zsh theme documentation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes) for an example that shows it, clearly, without the `"`'s on the value.

Comment: Actually, whether there are `"`s around `random` would not make a difference. The real issue is, that - according to the error message and contrary to the code snippets - curly double quotation marks (`“` and `”`, Unicode `U+201C` and `U+201D`) were used instead of straight quotation marks (`"`, ASCII `0x22`).

Comment: @Adaephon yea, it was easier to tell him to remove the quotes than to stop using unicode characters. :)